# How to hide the *Org Links* buffer when insert org links

Tags: org-mode

When insert org links with org-insert-link, an *Org Links* buffer is created.

How can I hide it?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the definition of the command (pressing `M-. org-insert-link`),
I modified the body by commenting these lines out

```
;;       (org-switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Org Links*")
;;       (with-current-buffer "*Org Links*"
;;  (erase-buffer)
;;  (insert "Insert a link.
;; Use TAB to complete link prefixes, then RET for type-specific completion support\n")
;;  (when org-stored-links
;;    (insert "\nStored links are available with <up>/<down> or M-p/n \
;; \(most recent with RET):\n\n")
;;    (insert (mapconcat #'org-link--prettify
;;               (reverse org-stored-links)
;;               "\n")))
;;  (goto-char (point-min)))
;;       (let ((cw (selected-window)))
;;  (select-window (get-buffer-window "*Org Links*" 'visible))
;;  (with-current-buffer "*Org Links*" (setq truncate-lines t))
;;  (unless (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-max))
;;    (org-fit-window-to-buffer))
;;  (and (window-live-p cw) (select-window cw)))
```

and it seems to be working fine without displaying *Org Links* buffer,
though you may have to test this for a while. It's tedious to do this every time org receives an update. Try redefining the function without the mentioned lines if it works for you.